# What data structure or mix of data structures would I use for a concurrent queue that allows for bulk and specific deletes?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, concurrency

Here is my problem, I need a data structure that behaves like a `queue`, but has some other properties:

- I should be able to easily delete items given a `tag` (every item in this queue has a `tag` that groups them)
- I also need to be able to delete one item given a `key` (all items added to the collection will have such a unique key). Here, if it simplifies things, I could remove by `tag` and `key` if it would make it faster.
- This collection is used in a concurrent environment so using as little locking as possible would be awesome
- It should have the usual FIFO properties of a queue. I do not need to access items not in head, but i need the **deleting** behavior above to work.

I'm using C# to build this solution but I'd be much more interested in algorithms and data structures definitions as I hardly believe any of the available collections meet my needs.

Papers, books, blog posts and any other kind of reference to this are really welcome.

Comment: If it is used in a concurrent environment will need to lock or make atomic the act of generating a unique ID, removal and additions which is pretty much everything this queue does.

Comment: The `key` is generated out of the queue, not on it. The item added already contains this unique id.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you can use a concurrent singly-linked list for the queue part. For the delete-by-key part you could keep a concurrent hash-table (striped locks are easy to do) pointing to nodes in the queue.

If that approach fails, look at how database systems do this. They *can* do all of what you want, concurrently. They maintain a primary copy of the data in a b-tree and maintain secondary b-tree indices. For locking, they use a concurrent hash-table. B-trees have nice concurrency properties because you can easily share-lock the upper parts of them even while you update the leaves under an exclusive lock.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a doubly multi-linked lists and two hashtables.

- One part of list for the queue
- Another part for grouping nodes by tag
- One hashtable for accessing a node by key
- Another hashtable for accessing nodes by a tag

Examples in Python (I'm sorry...)

**Inserting an element:**

```
 items_table['item_key'] = new_item

 my_queue.tail.next = new_item
 new_item.previous = my_queue.tail
 my_queue.tail = new_item

 new_item.next_by_tag = tags_table['item_tag'] #head of tag's list
 tags_table['item_tag'].previous_by_tag = new_item
 tags_table['item_tag'] = new_item
```

**Removing a element by key:**

```
item = key_table['node_key']

item.next.previous = item.previous
item.previous.next = item.next

item.next_by_tag.previous_by_tag = item.previous_by_tag
item.previous_by_tag.next_by_tag = item.next_by_tag

del item
```

**Removing a element by tag:**

```
def remove_elements_by_tag(tag_head):
    if tag_head == None:
        return
    else:
        remove_elements_by_tag(tag_head.next_by_tag)
        tag_head.next.previous = tag_head.previous
        tag_head.previous.next = tag_head.next
```

Something like that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats close to the solution I wrote already (a linked hash set with a hash map for tag deletes), but it used in a concurrent environment, so i need a lot of locks to make something like that and it doesn't feel like the best solution. Got some hints from Rodrigo Kumpera and Andrei Formiga about a solution based on a concurrent queue and lazy deletes and it feels like it would be a nice solution for it (you can catch the discussion on my FB timeline - https://www.facebook.com/mauricio.linhares/posts/281814491927760 PT only, sorry). I'll implement the solution and see how it goes.